# Eiffel: best practices for creation procedures

Tags: eiffel, creation-pattern

### Animal

```
deferred class ANIMAL
inherit
    ANY
        redefine
            default_create
        end
feature

    creator: like Current

    guts: GUTS

    default_create
        do
            create guts
        end

    make_malformed
        do
            default_create
        end

end --class
```

### PIG

```
class PIG

inherit
    ANIMAL
        redefine
            make_malformed
        end

create
    default_create,
    make_malformed,
    make_from_insemination

feature
    guts: GUTS

    make_malformed
        do
            Precursor
            set_left_eye (create {MALFORMED_EYE})
        end

    make_from_insemination (some_humain: HUMAIN)
        do
            default_create
            creator := some_humain
        end

end --class
```

Into my vision of best practices, I'll say that

- If there is no particular sense of making a creation procedure (like my `make_malformed` example) redefine the `default_create`
- All creation procedure should call `default_create` and add specific behavior (like my `make_from_db` example)
- So *what is the purpose* of many libraries in *Eiffel* which are adding a `make` like `create {LINKED_LIST}.make`

Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Eiffel libraries were developed before `default_create` was added to `ANY` with the corresponding semantics. This explains why many classes of the base library do not use it.

Also, creation procedures can carry some specific sense. For example, `make` can create a container that compares internal objects using reference equality whereas `make_equal` can create a container that uses object equality instead (this is the case for `HASH_TABLE`, though there is an additional argument to indicate an expected number of elements, this argument could be omitted with some other design choice). In such cases, `default_create` and `default_create_equal` would be non-symmetric, whereas `make` and `make_equal` are symmetric, so that the design is more consistent.

As you point out, `default_create` should not carry any specific behavior, just some basic things, expected from all descendants.

Whether `default_create` should be called by all other creation procedures heavily depends on the design. One example, where this is almost a rule, is the library *"vision"* that encodes in `default_create` a correct order of initialization, crucial for void safety. It's still possibly to write a class (based on this library) that performs the initialization correctly without calling `default_create` in its creation procedure, but having a ready-to-follow patters simplifies development.